# What is this abbreviation from Virginia tax records?

Tags: palaeography, 18th-century, virginia

I'm unable to decode this abbreviation:

> [image]

For a male (due to 1 tithe being charged) Brizendine surname in Essex County, Virginia 1782 personal tax list.

Here is the whole page for context.  See almost halfway down the left edge for the above snippet.

> [image]

I see nothing like it elsewhere on the page.  Perhaps it is for the estate of Francis?  Perhaps there are two characters, maybe for an abbreviation for Thomas?  Perhaps it is for Elizabeth and the male over 21 is a son of hers?  Looking at the year following, I'm unable to find a matching Brizendine in the following year's tax list.